# how to use PHP to get the contents of a URL hidden by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to pull the content of a certain URL, say for example, google.com.

I use

```
$url = 'www.google.com';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

to get the contents of google, then I use
htmlentities to pull out the source code so that I can get the content I want.

However, for some website, there is a javascript redirecting me to other websites.
So that when I use `file_get_content` to get the source code, I am capturing the source code from other websites.

the javascript that redirects the website is:

`body onLoad="document.AutoRedirect.submit()"`

I want to know how I can get rid of this javascript and get the source code of the webpage I want?

I am just new to PHP and I hope the explanation could be in details.
Many thanks!

Comment: JavaScript redirection only works when the JS is executed, when you fetch the content the JS code is not executed.

Comment: By the way, the website I am trying to get is Yamato delivery company package tracking site. I have the connote number and I want to take down the tracking information on the page. However when I enter the URL of Yamato it will redirect me to somewhere that I cannot use get_content to get the source code.

Comment: They may be checking your useragent string and then redirecting you.

Comment: Exactly, some sites are redirecting to subpages for the robots, so it might be it.

Comment: Use curl and provide valid user agents

Comment: typical web scraping job for headless browser phantomjs and co. https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use CURL to simulate a browser request from your robot-like request.
It is better to read [PHP's Documentation on cURL](https://php.net/curl)